# Do cauchy sequence in closed set not necessarily convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis

We know that cauchy sequence in complete set convergence,but cauchy sequence in closed set do not necessarily convergence. Are there some counterexamples ?

Answer (score 4):

Take any space that isn't complete, such as $\Bbb Q$. It is closed in itself, but it isn't complete so it has Cauchy sequences which don't converge.

Answer (score 1):

As a specific example consider the decimal expansion sequence for any irrational number (for example $\pi$) as a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$
$$q_i = 10^{-i} \lfloor \pi \cdot 10^i \rfloor$$
$$q = (3,\frac{31}{10}, \frac{314}{100}, \ldots)$$
$q$ converges to $\pi \notin \mathbb{Q}$ and is a cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$. The set $A:=[3, \frac{32}{10}] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is closed in the topology of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $q_i \in A \quad \forall i \in \mathbb{N}_0$